# egrep to print output on the same line

Tags: shell, grep

I am running a command and filtering out multiple words using egrep but output is showing up in multiple lines, is there a way i can get the output in a single line with particular set of matched words.

```
egrep -n "name|recovery"
```

currently getting output as

```
6:    "name": "7660",
27:      "recovery": "2020-08-04",
40:    "name": "7667708",
61:      "recovery": "2020-08-03",
74:    "name": "7660271",
95:      "recovery": "2020-08-02",
```

Required output

```
1:    "name": "7660", "recovery": "2020-08-04"
2:    "name": "7667708", recovery": "2020-08-03"
3:    "name": "7660271", "recovery": "2020-08-02"
```

Comment: can you add sample input from which the present output is shown? that way you might get a simpler answer using `awk` instead of trying to process the current output with other tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe several commands to achieve that.

```
<<your command>> | cut -d: -f2- | sed '{N;s/,\n/,/;}' | grep -n '^'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the pattern for your results is every other line, an easy solution is to use the `paste` command. For example:

```
egrep -n "name|recovery" | paste - -
```

The output is separated by tabs by default. The technique is also useful when using `egrep -o` with multiple matches on the same line of source text.